# How do I store a Ordered Dictionary in Google Datastore on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Python OrderedDict which I want to store in the Google Datastore of Google App engine.
The OrderedDict has the structure:
{'link': {'title': title, 'weight': weight} }.
What is a good way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to be able to query it? Is there a reason you can't simply construct a model that matches it, especially given your fields seem to be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use [NDB's PickleProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#types), which can store any python object that can be pickled.

If that doesn't work, you could use an NDB JsonProperty with `repeated=True` and store key/value tuples. This would require special code to [de]serialize, but it would allow you to retain order information.